# How to split augmentedImageDatastore?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, input

I have an ImageDatastore and I want to split every file in it (because every file is 2 pics stick to each other, like 640*480 - rgb and right to it from 640 till 1240 *480 black and white).

Is there the way?

I thought maybe smth like this, but doesn't work

```
augimds = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize,imds);


imageSize = [1:480 1:1280 3];
augimds2 = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize,imds);
```

Comment: Can you post a sample image? Is the question about using ImageDatastore or about how to perform the splitting?

Comment: https://ibb.co/xGPFj5V the picture, and I need to split it into 2

Comment: Splitting code: `I1 = I(:, 1:640, :);I2 = I(:, 641:end, :);`

Comment: Yeah, but I need to apply it for ImageDatastore, since all my data is there

Comment: If I do smth like Data = imds.readall();
cropped_1 = Data(:, 1:640, :); it starts to say that my index at 2 position exceeds 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of R2019a, all Datastores have a transform function that can be used to modify the outcome of read. For example:

```
imds = imageDatastore(pathToYourImages);
dsLeftRightSplit = transform(imds,@(x) {x(:,1:640,:),x(:,641:end,:)});
figure
montage(read(dsLeftRightSplit))
```

Where in the code above the anonymous function takes x, the image returned by an imageDatastore read and returns a cell array with two images, split by indexing into the original image.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.transform.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom read function that read an image and crops the left half.

- Define a custom read function:

  ```
  function J = customreaderLeftSide(im_file_name)
      %Custom read function for imageDatastore: read file, and return the left half
      I = imread(im_file_name);
      J = I(:, 1:end/2, :); %Crop left half

      %In case you want the right half, use: J = I(:, end/2+1:end, :);
  end
  ```
- Set custom image reader function for your imageDatastore:

  ```
  imds.ReadFcn = @customreaderLeftSide;
  ```

---

I created a complete code sample that:

- Build 5 sample images for testing: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg. 5.jpg
- Create imageDatastore (maually select images 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg , 4.jpg, 5.jpg).
- Set custom image reader function.
- Execute `readall`, and display the third image.

Copy and paste the following code into an `m` file, to see how it works:

```
%Build images for testing: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg. 5.jpg
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
I = imread('peppers.png');
I1 = imresize(I, [480, 640]);
I2 = rgb2gray(I1);I2 = cat(3, I2, I2, I2);
J = [I1 I2];
for i = 1:5
    %Add number to each image (in case you don't have license, replace with K = J).
    K = insertText(J, [100, 100], num2str(i), 'FontSize', 72);
    imwrite(K, [num2str(i), '.jpg']);
    %figure;imshow(K);
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Create image data store (maually select images 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg , 4.jpg, 5.jpg)
imds = imageDatastore({'1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'});
imds.ReadFcn = @customreaderLeftSide; %Set custom image reader function.

%Read all images, and display the third image.
imgs = readall(imds);
imshow(imgs{3})


function J = customreaderLeftSide(im_file_name)
    %Custom read function for imageDatastore: read file, and return the left half
    I = imread(im_file_name);
    J = I(:, 1:end/2, :); %Crop left half
end
```

I hope you can customize the above example to your needs.